# How to Install and Use V-Calendar (vue.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'd like to use the V-Calendar library in my Vuetify app. The app had worked so far, but unfortunately I did not manage to install the V-Calendar library correctly.

No errors are displayed, but the website has stopped working. It becomes completely white and nothing is displayed. I followed [V-Calendar Installation](https://vcalendar.io/installation.html#npm).

### What I tried:

**1. NPM**

```
npm install v-calendar
```

**2. v-calendar.js in plugins folder**

- In the folder where `main.js` is located: New file `./plugins/v-calendar.js` created

**3. v-calendar.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VCalendar from 'v-calendar';

// Use v-calendar & v-date-picker components
Vue.use(VCalendar);

export default new VCalendar({
});
```

**4. main.js:**

```
...
import VCalendar from './plugins/v-calendar';
...
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  VCalendar,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

### EDIT 1:

I deleted `v-calendar.js`. I updated `main.js` (see @pretzelhammer answer).

**/views/Home.vue:**

```
<v-date-picker v-model="date" />
```

```
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data: () => ({
    date: new Date(),
  }),
};
```

Unfortunately no calendar is displayed.
`v-calender` works, but `v-date-picker` doesn't work.

### EDIT 2:

- **149 Errors:**

  - Examples:

    - [Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.
    - [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '[object Object]'. This may cause an update error.
    - [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Array, String, got Date. found in ---> < VDatePicker >
    - [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: dateString.split is not a function". found in ---> < VDatePicker >
- **1 Warning:**

  - [Vuetify] Value must be a String, got Date. found in ---> < VDatePicker >

### Update EDIT 2:

- I solved the the following two errors  as follows:

  - [Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.
  - [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '[object Object]'. This may cause an update error.
- Solution:

```
v-for="(item, id) in items" :key="id"
```

instead of:

```
v-for="item in items" :key="item"
```

Comment: i dont think you need to export a VCalendar instance in the plugin file and you don't need to include VCalendar in the Vue constructor as well,

Comment: thanks @AliHassan, I updated the code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in the console tab of DevTools? Also, are you using the latest version of the v-calendar library?

Comment: Yes, v-calendar is up to date (v2.1.1) and unfortunately I have a lot of errors and a warning. (see question)

Comment: @pretzelhammer I fixed all the "String" errors with new Date().toISOString(). Now I only have the following errors when I use v-date-picker: (1) [Vue warn]: Error in render: "RangeError: Invalid time value" and (2) RangeError: Invalid time value

Comment: I think the issue is that you're using the v-date-picker from vuetify instead of from v-calendar: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/

Comment: You're right. If I use the syntax on the Vuetify site then it works. But I would like to use V-Calendar. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work probably because both Vuetify and VCalendar try to globally register a `v-date-picker` component which is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't follow the instructions correctly. All you need to do is:

**1. NPM**

```sh
npm install v-calendar
```

**2. main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VCalendar from 'v-calendar';

// Use v-calendar & v-date-picker components
Vue.use(VCalendar, {
  componentPrefix: 'vc',
});

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

And then you'll be able to use the `vc-calendar` and `vc-date-picker` components in any of your Vue templates.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted v-calendar.js. In main.js I now have exactly that from you and also the imports for vuetify etc. At /views/Home.vue I have the following: <v-date-picker v-model="date" /> and in data: date: new Date(), Now I can see everything on the page again, but I don't see the calendar.

Comment: Please update your question with the source code for /views/Home.vue

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question here. I updated it.

Comment: @KplnMoon I've updated my answer again, it should work for you now.

Comment: I have a new question on this topic and I would be happy if you can help me with that too. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65294969/change-value-in-vc-date-picker-v-text-field-using-v-for