# Change :value in vc-date-picker > v-text-field using v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-for

I want `:value` to change from `inputValue.start` to `inputValue.end` automatically.
So when I click on the end date it should be updated in the second text field. Likewise, if I select a date range in the second text field, the first text field should also be updated again.
**At the end of this question you can see the result of both cases.**

**P.S.:** I use the V-Calendar plugin for Vue.js. The `vc-date-picker` element is from this plugin.

- HTML:

```html
<v-col v-for="(dateF, date_id) in datesF" :key="date_id + 'A'" cols="6" sm="3">
  <vc-date-picker v-model="range" color="red" is-range :input-debounce="500" :min-date="new Date()">
    <template v-slot="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
      <v-text-field 
        :value="inputValue.start" 
        v-on="inputEvents.start" 
        :label="dateF.label"
      />                          
    </template>
  </vc-date-picker>
</v-col>
```

- Script:

```js
<script>
  export default {
    name: "Home",
    data: () => ({
      datesF: [
        { label: "Start Date", val: "start" },
        { label: "End Date", val: "end" },
      ],
      range: {
        start: new Date(),
        end: new Date(),
      },
    }),
  }; 
</script>
```

[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atpWv.gif)
[Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iztdh.gif)

- **What I tried:**
  `:value="inputValue + '.' + dateF.val"` but that wasn't the solution.
- **EDIT:**
  Without `v-for` and twice `v-text-field` it works, but I want to use `v-for`. The reason is that otherwise I can't put the text fields in one line. No matter what I did, it didn't work. It only works with `v-for`, but for that I have to solve the main problem.

### Temporary Solution (with v-for)

See answer of @Gurkan Ugurlu.

- **The problem of this temporary solution**:
  No Live Update. See [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvkZw.gif).

### For Live Update my initial code:

I just output the data for testing and it worked. Every time you select a date range, console.log is executed with the current dates.

```html
watch: {
    range: {
      handler: function () {
        console.log(this.range.start.toLocaleDateString());
        console.log(this.range.end.toLocaleDateString());
      },
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Hope it helps :)

```html
<v-col v-for="(dateF, date_id) in datesF" :key="date_id + 'A'" cols="6" sm="3">
  <vc-date-picker v-model="range" color="red" is-range :input-debounce="500" :min-date="new Date()">
    <template v-slot="{ inputValue, inputEvents }">
      <v-text-field 
        :value="inputValue[dateF.val]" 
        v-on="inputEvents[dateF.val]" 
        :label="dateF.label"
      />                          
    </template>
  </vc-date-picker>
</v-col>
```

Comment: Tanks a lot! :) Now the text fields are in one line, but unfortunately the calendar does not work 100%. As you can see in my last [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvkZw.gif), the days clicked are not updated live, which is what usually happens with this plugin. It only works if I select an area directly in the first text field and do nothing in the second text field (or vice versa).

Comment: Maybe you can add a watcher and try forcing update.

Comment: There are a couple of methods on [this](https://vcalendar.io/datepicker.html) page under "Advanced Slots" and in the [API](https://vcalendar.io/api/v2.0/datepicker.html) that maybe can solve the problem. But I don't know how to include this in my code and how to use it in conjunction with a watcher. Do you have a tip or solution for me?

Comment: I started with watch (see question). Now I have to implement it in such a way that every time I select a day in the first calendar, it is also marked as the start date in the second calendar and vice versa. @GurkanUgurlu

Comment: I looked but i cant find the best answer. I think in watch value you can use reference and trigger the methods that v-calendar triggers